# PDO GROUP BY not returning results

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, pdo

I'm having a hard time to get a PDO database class i'm writing to play nicely with queries which us GROUP BY clauses.

For example, I want to retrieve a list of articles in the database, but the articles are linked to tags using a many to many relationship.

i.e. articles > article-tag-link < tags

The query I'm trying to run is very simple:

```
SELECT * FROM articles, article-tag-link, tags WHERE articles.articleID = article-tag-link.articleID AND tags.tagID = article-tag-link.tagID GROUP BY articles.articleID LIMIT 3;
```

I'm using a prepared statement to execute the query with PDO, and I know that simple queries without GROUP BY works perfectly as it is being used elsewhere no problems.

So, when it comes to executing the query, I'm doing:

```
$result = $stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This returns the results I want, although they're not grouped properly. I.e. one article which may have 3 tags, will appear three times (as there are technically three records satisfying the query - excluding the GROUP BY). So it's as if the GROUP BY is being ignored.

I've come across

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC | PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
$results = array_map('reset', $results);
```

But that behaves just as strangely. This will return only one result (it doesn't return the first article three times - once for each applied tag), but it will stop at that one single result - it doesn't continue to fetch two more.

Can anyone explain how to get it to fetch three unique records satisfying the query?

Comment: I have managed to find the solution myself and will write it up for anyone else who may have made the same mistake. As I had written my own PDO wrapper, I was passing in all of the values to be queries via a method. The method took care of preparing the statement and binding everything. What I was doing was accidentally trying to bind the GROUP BY value which was causing the issues. Just remember not to bind this, and have the GROUP BY as a regular part of the formatted query.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [INNER JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) instead

try this

```
   SELECT * FROM articles a
   INNER JOIN article-tag-link atl
      ON  a.articleID = atl.articleID 
   INNER JOIN tags t
      ON  t.tagID = atl.tagID 
   GROUP BY a.articleID 
   LIMIT 3;
```

try this

```
  $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: The query itself I wrote just for the sake of a simplified example, and works no problem if I run it directly within mySQL. It's the way that PDO is fetching the results that seems to be the issue.

Comment: I changed $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); to $results = $stmt->fetchAll(); but it still doesn't fetch the 3 results.. only one

Comment: That didn't work either.. I hard coded in your query to double check it wasn't my sql query and it yields the exact same results - so I know it's something to do with the way PDO is working.

Answer (score 0):

you spesific field show

```
SELECT articles.articleID FROM articles, article-tag-link, tags WHERE articles.articleID = article-tag-link.articleID AND tags.tagID = article-tag-link.tagID GROUP BY articles.articleID LIMIT 3;
```